# Word for happy/envious

Tags: single-word-requests

I had a friend over recently and he expressed happiness for our family and home life. He was envious but with no negative connotations. It is something he wants for himself but is happy we have it.  What would you call that?

Comment: I have never considered 'envy' to be resentful, but 'jealous' is, which more suggests "I want it, but you should not have it". [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/envy) carries no negativity for 'envy' but [Chambers](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=envy&title=21st) does.

Comment: ...saying to someone "I envy you" can be a compliment said up-front, whereas "I am jealous of you" is not, and is rarely actually spoken for that reason, but left on the back burner to simmer.

Comment: I find *vicarious joy* in your good fortune.